# Can somebody help me solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}} - \frac{y}{x}
$$

The question said use $y=u^2$ as the substitution to find the answer to the differential equation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried dividing both sides by 2sqrt(y), i tried solving it using homogeneous equations

Comment: The homogeneous approach should have given a substantial simplification. How far did you go?

Comment: What do you get when you do that substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Setting $y=u^2$ and differentiating both sides we get that $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2u \frac{du}{dx}$. Substituting these into the original equations gives,

$$2u \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{u}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{u^2}{x}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} + \frac{u}{2x} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$

This is a linear equation, and so the integrating factor is,

$$I(u,x) = e^{\int{\frac{1}{2x}}dx}=\sqrt{x}$$

Multiplying through by this $I(u,x)$,

$$\sqrt{x} \frac{du}{dx} + \frac{u}{2 \sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x} u) = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{x} u = \frac{x}{2} + c$$

$$y = (\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2} + \frac{c}{\sqrt{x}})^2 = \frac{x}{4} + \frac{c^2}{x} + c$$